# Problemas em conectar Node.JS Express em MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, node.js, express.js

Eu sei que meu projeto está correto que não existe nada de errado, eu acho que o problema é meu banco recém instalado, como poderei resolver esse problema?

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
    at Utils.Promise.tap.then.catch.err (C:\SQL\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\connection-manager.js:149:19)
    at tryCatcher (C:\SQL\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\SQL\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\SQL\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\SQL\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\SQL\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:689:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (C:\SQL\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\SQL\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\SQL\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:696:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:667:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:649:5)
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado, valeu mesmo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com a resposta da pergunta [**MySQL 8.0 - Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50131831/3388148):

> Execute a seguinte `query` no `MySQL Workbench`
>
> ```
> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'
> ```
>
> Tente reconectar o `Node.js` após fazê-lo